# Please check if my answer is correct or not.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Question:- John wants to burn 250 calories in a day by doing physical activity. He chooses walking and running stairs for the same and plans to spend 't' hours in walking and 's' hours in running stairs. Write a linear equation in two variables for this situtuation by using the given data-
1. Walking burns 4 kilo calories in 1 minute. 
2. Running Upstairs burns 10 kilo calories in 1 minute. 
My Answer:-
Required calories to be burned = 250
= 0.25 kilo calories. 
Calories spent on walking = (4*60*t) = 240t.
Calories spent on Running stairs = (10*60*s) = 600s. 
Therefore, the equation is:-
240t + 600s = 0.25 (Answer)
Have I made a mistake in the solution?

Comment: This problem has a nasty subtlety to the units in it, give the beginning of this a read and you'll see what I mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Add the (solution-verification) tag for requests to evaluate a solution.  It displays as (proof-verification) and either one can be added as tag with the same effect.

Comment: According to your equation, John can get by with 1.5 seconds of stair running per day. If only losing weight were that simple! You are confusing calories with kilocalories here (or perhaps it's the question setter's fault). To be honest, this is a very easy mistake to make.

Comment: I also agree that there is a problem in the units. The question is probably incorrect.

Comment: You can easily adjust for the unit conundrum (once you know what the proper conversion factor is), do you see how?